# creating a active url class

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter-url

Hello I just started working with CI ( codeigniter) and everything went well till now, except my navigation part. I've used the url class for now with the anchor method to create the urls but I also want the current url to have a class="current" for example so that I can style it.

Can someone show me how to do this?

my link is created as follows:

```
$this->load->helper('url');

$menu_item = array(
    '/home' => 'Home',
    '/schiphol' => 'Schiphol Service',
    '/tarieven' => 'Tarieven en Acties',
    '/kwaliteit' => 'Kwaliteit',
    //'/news' => 'news'
    '/contact' => 'Contact'
);
```

and in my view

```
        <nav role="navigation" class="mainnav">
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($menu_item as $menu => $key): ?>
        <li> <?php echo anchor($menu, $key) ?> </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

but in the anchor method I can give a 3rd method with the class but how can I do this only for the current url?

Comment: So what have you tried to do to achieve this?

Comment: can you put in the `anchor()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a 3rd attribute, not a method.

You have to use the uri class to compare the current url with the one in the loop:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

```
<?php foreach ($menu_item as $menu => $key): ?>
 <li> 
 <?php echo anchor($menu, $key, $this->uri->segment(1) == $menu ? 'class="active"' : '') ?>
 </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not working I neither get active or class=""